# How can I expand a fireplace box in a framed wall?

Tags: walls, framing, fireplace

We're creating a bumped-out wall with an inset fireplace (ventless, bioethanol), similar to [this](http://st.houzz.com/simgs/70c11d4b006ef61b_8-9250/contemporary-family-room.jpg) to give you an idea.

[image]

One notable difference however is that the bottom of the fireplace will be about 12 inches off the floor.

I framed out the wall with 2x6's, leaving a box to insert the fireplace into, only in my attempts to be as exact as possible, I didn't leave quite enough clearance to get the box in.  I'm sure the box isn't exactly plumb and square, and additionally, the fireplace box itself has domed screws that stick out farther than the listed dimensions in the instruction manual.

Is there a good way to "shave" down the insides of the lumber to allow the fireplace to go in? At this point, the wall is already in-place and has been ramset-nailed into the floor, so any advice to avoid having to bring the wall down would be great.

Comment: How much more clearance do you need?

Comment: Sorry, should have added that in.  I think I may need about an additional 1/8th to 1/4th of an inch on each side.  Enough that using my orbital sander to do it will take a long time.

Comment: Just in case anyone is interested, I ended up basically deconstructing the inner box, removing/rearranging studs.  I added air gaps and firecode drywall to the inside of the box for extra protection. Had to use a sawzall, forstner bits, wood chisels, and the orbital sander to get everything done.

Comment: Once during a remodel to, among other things, install a window I got to reframe it **three** times before I got it right.  The first redo was because I didn't measure the window, just copied the other window framing which was a cheat with chiseled out edges.  (Don't recall what the second redo was about.)  [All lessons are repeated until learned.](http://www.school-for-champions.com/life/rules_for_the_game_of_life.htm#.U8bOVU2AUkA)

Comment: @wallyk, haha, thanks for the anecdote. Glad to hear I'm not the only one, and that you too were able to solve your problem.  Perfect quote :).

Answer (score 1):

You would normally use a plane to remove the wood needed to get the fireplace in.  If it is just a little bit of wood needed removed you could try a belt sander.